# getting 401 error when i call the api with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am new with mocha, right now i am doing api call invocation with mocha, but i am getting this error `Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (domain, _events, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 401` , can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?  here is my full code of it

```
it('Get Organizations', function(done) {
    let current_token = currentResponse['token'];
    let headers = [{"content-type":"application/json","vrc-access-token": current_token }];

    console.log(headers);

    chai.request(app)
    .post('entities')
    .set(headers)
    .send({"key":"organizations","operation":"findAll"})      
    .end(function (err, res) {
        currentResponse = res.body;
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just based on the [docs](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#setting-up-requests), it doesn't look like chai-http supports setting headers in this way, they need to be added separately i.e.

```
chai.request(app)
  .post('entities')
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('vrc-access-token', current_token)
  .send({"key":"organizations","operation":"findAll"})      
  .end(function (err, res) {
    currentResponse = res.body;
    expect(err).to.be.null;
    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    done();
  });
```